# Is it haram to have a photo album in the cupboard?

Tags: halal-haram

I have a photo album with photographs inside (photos of me and family/friends when we were younger and older). This photo album is in my closed cupboard in my bedroom. I only add photographs in the album if I have any physical copies (polaroid photographs) and then return it in the cupboard for a long time.

I know that framing or placing photos in public rooms (like living room, bedroom, etc) is haram, but what about if it's in an album in the cupboard where it is not visible?

Answer (score 1):

As photography didn't exist in the times of the prophet and of the founders of fiqh schools, only recent scholarly opinions exist;
Some say a photo is the same as a picture, and others say that a photo is different from a picture as it only reproduces reality, and is hence no way competing God's Creation.
The second matter, that pictures were mainly used for worship doesn't apply to your photo album.
Shia schools and the Maliki school allow pictures. There's no passage in the Quran forbidding pictures, and according to the Torah God forbids pictures or sculpture for worship.

You can decide whom you trust.

See e.g. https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa/7728/photographs-please-clarify-your-position/